# Why does Potassium Sorbate have two CAS numbers? - Should these not be unique?

Tags: organic-chemistry

Potassium Sorbate has two CAS numbers - 24634-61-5; 590-00-1. Should these not be unique?

Comment: Related for FeOOH: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/40572/why-does-feooh-have-two-cas-numbers?r=SearchResults

Comment: If the same goes for Potassium Sorbate as for FeOOH - Then can someone enlighten me towards the nature of the two CAS numbers:

Comment: Or rather let me rephrase - which is the  the ‘boring’ laboratory version of the Potassium Salt and which is the unambiguous refencing of the preservative used in foodstuffs?

Comment: Please [edit] the question, instead of trying to seek clarification in the comments.